# SQLCE performance in windows phone very poor

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I've writing this thread as I've fought this problem for three whole days now!

Basically, I have a program that collects a big CSV-file and uses that as input to a local SQLCE-database.
For every row in this CSV-file (which represents some sort of object, lets call it "dog"), I need to know whether this dog already exists in the database.
If it already exists, don't add it to the database.
If it doesn't exists, add a new row in the database.

The problem is, every query takes around 60 milliseconds (in the beginning, when the database is empty) and it goes up to about 80ms when the database is around 1000 rows big.
When I have to go thru 1000 rows (which in my opinion is not much), this takes around 70000 ms = 1 minute and 10 seconds (just to check if the database is up to date), way too slow! Considering this amount will probably some day be more than 10000 rows, I cannot expect my user to wait for over 10 minutes before his DB is synchronized.
I've tried to use the compiled query instead, but that does not improve performance.

The field which im searching for is a string (which is the primary key), and it's indexed.

If it's necessary, I can update this thread with code so you can see what I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL CE on Windows Phone isn't the fastest of creatures but you can optimise it:

This article covers a number of things you can do:[WP7 Local DB Best Practices](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Performance-Best-Practices-Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database)

They als provide a WP7 project that can be downloaded so you can play with the code.

On top of this article I'd suggest changing your PK from a string to an int; strings take up more space than ints so your index will be larger and take more time to load from isolated storage.  Certainly in SQL Server searchs of strings are slower than searches of ints/longs.